# data.frame values as arguments for function in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
params <- data.frame(par1=TRUE, par2=TRUE, par3=TRUE)
```

I would like to use it as an argument to a function call like this:

```
fun(params[1, ])
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it:

```
fun <- function(x) print(x)  # example function
params<-data.frame( par1=TRUE, par2=TRUE, par3 = TRUE)

fun(params[1,])
```